# How to display a result in .innerHTML from a chosen answer in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to make a website which asks some questions and then will generate 3 random locations based on the users answers. The part I am struggling with is getting the end result to output the locations based on the first question in the object which is:

```
const questions = [
{
    "question": "What area of the world are you thinking of discovering next?",
    "answer1": "Europe",
    "answer1Array": "europeArray",
    "answer2": "Asia",
    "answer2Array": "asiaArray",
    "answer3": "America",
    "answer3Array": "americaArray",
    "answer4": "Australasia",
    "answer4Array": "australasiaArray"        
},

let europeArray1 = ['Algarve - Portugal', 'Asturias and Covadonga - Spain', 'Mdina & Zebbug - Malta']
let asiaArray1 = ['Yakushima Island - Japan', 'Mount Wudang Shan - China', 'Bantayan Island - Philippines'] etc...
```

I have then created a function to give me back a random location:

```
let finalEuropeArray1 = europeArray1.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
});
```

and finally a function to output 3 results

```
function randomHoliday (array) {
if (array == europeArray1) {
    return finalEuropeArray1.slice(europeArray1,3);
} else if (array == americaArray1) {
    return finalAmericaArray1.slice(americaArray1,3);
} else if (array == asiaArray1 {
    return finalAsiaArray1.slice(asiaArray1,3);
} else {
    return finalAustralasiaArray1.slice(australasiaArray1,3);
}
```

I am able to return 3 separate values with a function calling the first element in each:

```
let resultA = function seperateArrayA (randomHoliday) {
return `1. ${randomHoliday[0]}`;}
let resultB = function seperateArrayB (randomHoliday) {
return `2. ${randomHoliday[1]}`;}
let resultC = function seperateArrayC (randomHoliday) {
return `3. ${randomHoliday[2]}`;}
```

but I do not know how to output this in my final .innerHTML based on the first question in the questions object. I can only get it to work by putting in a manual entry e.g. `${resultA(australasiaArray1)}`

```
if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
    container.style.display = 'none';
    result.innerHTML =
    `<h1 class="final-score">Our Top 3 Recommendations:</h1>
    <div class="summary">
        <p><br></br></p>
        <p>${resultA(australasiaArray1)}</p>
        <p>${resultB(australasiaArray1)}</p>
        <p>${resultC(australasiaArray1)}</p>
    </div>
    <button class="restart">Restart Quiz</button>
     `
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup can be simplified by using nested objects for related answers, checkout the demo below:

```js
const questions = [
    {
        "question": "What area of the world are you thinking of discovering next?",
        "answers": {
            "Europe": {
                "label": "Europe",
                "locations": ['Algarve - Portugal', 'Asturias and Covadonga - Spain', 'Mdina & Zebbug - Malta']
            },
            "Asia": {
                "label": "Asia",
                "locations": ['Yakushima Island - Japan', 'Mount Wudang Shan - China', 'Bantayan Island - Philippines']
            }
        }
    }
];


let getRandomLocationForAnswer = function (question, answer) {;
    const possibleLocations = question.answers[answer].locations;
    const randomIndex = Math.floor((Math.random()*possibleLocations.length));

    return possibleLocations[randomIndex];
}

let buildSelect = function(questions){
    return questions.map((question, index) => {
      const possibleAnswers = Object.keys(question.answers);
    
      return`<select class="question" data-question-index="${index}">${possibleAnswers.map(l => `<option value="${l}">${l}</option>`)}</select>`;
    }).join('');
}

let showResults = function(questions, questionIndex, answer){
  const question = questions[questionIndex];
  
  document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML =
    `<h1 class="final-score">Our Top 3 Recommendations:</h1>
    <div class="summary">
        <p><br></br></p>
        <p>${getRandomLocationForAnswer(question, answer)}</p>
        <p>${getRandomLocationForAnswer(question, answer)}</p>
        <p>${getRandomLocationForAnswer(question, answer)}</p>
    </div>
    <button class="restart">Restart Quiz</button>
     `
}

document.querySelector('#questions').innerHTML += buildSelect(questions);
document.querySelectorAll('.question').forEach(question => {
  question.addEventListener('change', e => {
    const select = e.currentTarget;
    showResults(questions, parseInt(select.dataset.questionIndex), select.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<section id="questions">

</section>

<section id="results">

</section>
```

Comment: Thank you this is much simpler than my method, how would i put this as a variable in my final code snippet to list location in the .innerHTML
1.
2.
3.

Comment: How is the answer of a user determined? Do they just type in `Europe` and `Asia`? @ShrewdStyle

Comment: They have 7 questions to answer in total and the first question is based on what continent they are wanting to travel to, so i need to eliminate all of the arrays except the one that have selected, they have 4 options in the questions represented by input[type="radio"]

Comment: I updated the answer to include showing the results. @ShrewdStyle

Comment: Thanks for posting your code, I would however recommend changing it a bit to be able to remove the duplicate code. Is the provided code clear enough to implement the rest with a lot less duplication? @ShrewdStyle

Comment: yes thank you, i will redo it again now with your advice so that should keep my busy for the rest of the day

Comment: Great, good luck! If you have any more questions just send it in the chat. Could you mark the answer as solution so others with a similar question can find this answer? @ShrewdStyle

Answer (score 1):

resultA, resultB, resultC are functions, not values. if you put them in the template you will get a function reference and not the result of the function. To get the result you need to call the function(which you do in the last code snippet).

in order to get it to work simply define variables and set them to the function result:

```
    if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
    container.style.display = 'none';
    var l_resultA = resultA(australasiaArray1)
    ...
    result.innerHTML =
       `<h1 class="final-score">Our Top 3 Recommendations:</h1>
           <div class="summary">
              <p><br></br></p>
              <p>${l_resultA}</p>
              ....
           </div>
        <button class="restart">Restart Quiz</button>`
};
```